# XMPP multi-user-chat get user list

Tags: xmpp

get a list of all users and the status of XMPP multi-user-chat
I do so

```xml
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    id='kl2fax27'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

getting a list but without status.
I need for all users on the statuses to know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html), which describes the multi-user chat (MUC) protocol.  You need to join the room:

```
<presence
    from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/thirdwitch'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>
```

You'll then get a presence stanza from each occupant of the room with their current status:

```
<presence
    from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/firstwitch'
    to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <item affiliation='owner' role='moderator'/>
  </x>
</presence>

<presence
    from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/secondwitch'
    to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <item affiliation='admin' role='moderator'/>
  </x>
</presence>
```

And before you ask, no, there is no way to tell when you're "done" receiving these notifications, since users may come and go at any time.  You are now subscribed to the presence changes of the occupants, and have to keep track of what is current on the receiving side.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, there is indeed a way to tell the so-called [Presence Broadcast](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-pres) after joining a room is finished: The final presence is always the self-presence, which is indicated by a ```<status code='110'/>```.

Comment: @max.weller I'm pretty sure there are implementations that get that wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the [XMPP RFC](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html), I see that statuses are conveyed by presence messages, and that you ask another entity to report its status now (rather than waiting for it to tell you in a broadcast) by sending a `probe` status request to which you'll get a *directed* response ([§5.5 of the RFC](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#rfc.section.5.5) gives some examples). It's up to you to interpret what they say back correctly, of course…